# Erlang: Error when calling a returned function without assigning it to any variable

Tags: erlang

I was trying out some erlang code and I am not sure why we have to wrap code in parentheses in some place to work whereas in some other place it work without parentheses as well. Is it due to operator precedence (very unlikely), or due to being statement instead of expression? Erlang newbie here. Please see the examples below.

```
%% Example from the Programming Erlang book.
-module(lib_misc).
-export([for/3]).

for(Max, Max, F) -> [F(Max)];
for(I, Max, F)   -> [F(I)|for(I+1, Max, F)].
```

I use the above function to generate a list of functions

```
lib_misc:for(1, 10, fun (X) -> (fun () -> 2*X end) end).
```

giving something like

```
[#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,
 #Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,
 #Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,
 #Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,
 #Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>]
```

Next I tried will calling the function immediately to get the computed result, with three different variation producing the same result and assign it to a variable `L`.

```
L = lib_misc:for(1, 10, fun (X) -> (fun () -> 2*X end) end).

lib_misc:for(1, 10, fun (X) -> (fun () -> 2*X end ()) end).     %% [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
lib_misc:for(1, 10, fun (X) -> (fun () -> 2*X end)() end).      %% [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
lib_misc:for(1, 10, fun (X) -> fun () -> 2*X end() end).        %% [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

**The problem is when I call**

```
lists:nth(3, L)().
```

which gives the error `* 1: syntax error before: '('`. Why is this not giving `6`? `lists:nth()` is a function which in this case returns another function. So what is causing this problem?
Wrapping the statement in parenthesis gives the expected result, but why so?

```
(lists:nth(3, L))().  %% 6
```

Similarly, assigning the return value to a variable and calling it works, but that's obvious.

```
-module(test).
-export([l/0, t/0]).

l() -> lib_misc:for(1, 10, fun (X) -> (fun () -> 2*X end) end).
%% t() -> lists:nth(3, l())(). %% test.erl:5: syntax error before: '('
t() -> lists:nth(3, l()).      %% works.
```

If the problem is with statement expression thing, in this code `fun (X) -> fun () -> 2*X end() end` is the inner anonymous function a statement or an expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply an effect of the precedence rules in the Erlang grammar. (And there are no statements in Erlang, only expressions.)